# Unable to connect Windows Mobile 6 emulator to internet in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: emulation, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-mobile-6, virtual-pc-2007

I am working on modifying a windows mobile 6 application. I need to demo this using an emulator in a Windows Server 2012 R2 environment.

I was able to successfully download Device Emulator Manager,  mobile device center, and the required emulator images. I was also able to connect to the emulator.

I am, however, unable to connect the emulator to internet. I have changed the connection setting to DMA and have tried configuring the emulator to specific network cards. The issue is it is prompting me to download and install Virtual PC 2007. However, Windows Server 2012 R2 is not supported.

Any instruction on how I can get an alternative or even steps to have the emulator to connect to internet and to be able to see the content of the emulator in order to be able to install the CAB files, I would greatly appreciate it.

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2
Platform: Windows Mobile 6
Synchronization: Mobile Device Center

Answer (score 0):

VirtualPC is (was) needed for emulating an ethernet connection for emulated WM image. This already outdated for a long time...

You need only a DMA connection and then 'dock' the emulated device. WMDC should come up which has a connection setting for "This computer connects to" [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/2006/11/20/wmdcactivesync-pass-through-feature/]. Set this to Internet and the 'docked' emulated device will have internet access using the WMDC PASSTHRU feature.

If WMDC does not come up when the emulated device starts up, you may use the Stand-Alone device emulator (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25191). If the device is started, the Stand-Alone-DevEmu shows it as connected and you can right click the emulated 'machine' and select 'Dock' from the popup menu. Then WMDC will come up (hopefully) and provides the PASSTHRU connection.